# How can I split power from wall sconce switch to power a ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I am trying to tackle my first "bigger" electrical diy project by adding in a ceiling fan. Refinishing a room and a light switch currently controls two wall sconces on the opposite wall. The switch has 3 wires (black, white, and red + ground). I would like to add in a stacked 2 switch, one for the sconces and one for the ceiling fan to be added. My question is, can I power off of the existing switch? If so, what do I do with the red wire? Yes, I know I can hire an electrician, just trying to figure out on my own if possible. If not confident, then comes the contractor.

Comment: Pics of the wiring inside the box and how they are attached to the switch are needed to help.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and use the "sun & mountains" button to add some pics.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming US: With the red wire involved, you either have a two-way circuit or a switch loop.

If there are *only* three wires in the box, it is a switch loop and you can't tap power there; you need to tap it from the lamp.

If there are two cables coming into the box and the switch is connected between them (black on one side. Black and red in the other), it's a three-way circuit. Depending on exactly how that was wired and which of the two switches you are looking at, either switched or unswitched power may be available. You'd need to take a probe to the wires to determine which.